# Excluding NPM dependencies on a per-package basis

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, npm

I have a package (d3.js) in my `package.json` for a given project. When `npm install` is run for the project, I would like npm **not** to install any dependencies related to d3.js itself, nor run any install scripts for it. In other words, I would like npm to just fetch the package and unpack it into `node_modules` so that it can still be accessed as a regular package, but not do anything else with it.

My reason for this is that a regular `npm install` for this particular package requires `node-gyp` to be run, and the build pipe I have to use (not under my control) does not support any kind of native compilation, hence the install fails. However, the package already includes pre-compiled `.js` files, which are the only things I am interested in, and hence the install process is not even necessary.

Is this at all doable?

Comment: To remove packages being installed by NPM, edit the package.json file i.e remove the line which contains the package you don't want installed. However, installing certain module will install all other modules on which it depends.

Comment: npm install does download the packages and puts them into the node_modules folder. Also check package.json file for specific commands or scripts. If scripts key contains a name of a script, then npm will run that script.

Comment: I can certainly avoid the problem by simply not depending on the package. However, I do want to depend on it - I simply do not want to run any install scripts associated with it.

Comment: Well I cannot read your mind. Read these docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: I indeed know how package.json and associated scripts work - my question is about *avoiding* these scripts being run during the install phase for specific packages.

Comment: check a specific module documentation. I have never had a need to hack into npm module internals just so npm installs all of them. My recomendations is, remove node_modules folder and try npm install again. But of course you can work on D3js app without Node or NPM.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand what I want to do. Sorry if the question is unclear, and thanks for your time.

Comment: No. Vanilla npm does not have this functionality.

Comment: npm supports running install with `--ignore-scripts` but that disables all scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, the answer is **no**. It does not seem like this is a planned feature for NPM either, nor could I find it provided by Yarn (which I am now using instead).